# Substitute to p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to display a form using a bean with the framework JSF and primefaces.

It is very simple to do with dataTable as followed but it is also not suitable at all for this form.

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{utilisateur.questionnaire.questions}" var="question" styleClass="borderless" class="ui-g">
<p:column value="" class="ui-g-2">#{question.titreQuestion}</p:column>
<p:column value="" class="ui-g-5">#{question.question}</p:column>
<p:column value="" class="ui-g-5"><h:inputText id="firstName" value="default}" label=""></h:inputText></p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="../admin.xhtml"></h:commandButton>
```

As you can see below it does not look very professional. There is an empty head bar. Moreover, sometimes a question has no title in the left column so there is an empty cell (which would not be important if the cell had not a background color).
[image]

Thus, have you any recommendation of a tag for this type of form where I could have two string (retrieved via the bean using *#{utilisateur.questionnaire.questions}*) on the first line and the inputText on the second one and so on.

I have tried with h:panelGrid, unfortunately you cannot have * value="#{utilisateur.questionnaire.questions}" * inside the tag...

Comment: Start by removing the ui-g styleclasses. They are not meant for the datatable. Improvement, right? And you can easily hide the headers with css.

Comment: If I remove them it is worst... I have after 3 exact column of the same size... I am really interested by the css (or a link of how to remove it) !

Comment: Better not use tables for grid behaviour. Go with a CSS framework like bootstrap or do it with flexbox: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: It looks better... just use look at the PF docs how to set column widths.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: that is what PF grid-css does (e.g. combined with a `ui:repeat`. OP just create wrong combinations (datatable with grid-css). And PF datatable is perfectly usable for this since it also is responsive